# Cannot run appium tests in Bitrise (java+selenide+ios)

Tags: java, appium, selenide, bitrise

I am trying to run automation tests in Bitrise but got an error. I can run my tests on my local machine and everything is ok.

> device: simulator iOS 15.4
> machine: Xcode 13.3.x on macOS 12.2
> java: 17
> selenide 6.4.0
> appium 1.22.3
> gradle 7.4
> Node.js: 12.22.11
> NPM: 6.14.16

Could you please help me?

```
2022-04-18T15:44:02.335+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] com.tunein.mobile.tests.ios.IosBooksAroundFirstTest.beforeTest STARTED
2022-04-18T15:44:02.390+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
2022-04-18T15:44:02.390+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] com.tunein.mobile.tests.ios.IosBooksAroundFirstTest.beforeTest FAILED
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:585)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:225)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:164)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:79)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:87)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.<init>(IOSDriver.java:105)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.tunein.mobile.appium.driverprovider.IosDriverProvider.createDriver(IosDriverProvider.java:73)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.DefaultDriverFactory.createInstanceOf(DefaultDriverFactory.java:40)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.DefaultDriverFactory.create(DefaultDriverFactory.java:29)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.createWebDriverInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:109)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.createWebDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:69)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.CreateDriverCommand.lambda$createDriver$1(CreateDriverCommand.java:80)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.codeborne.selenide.logevents.SelenideLogger.get(SelenideLogger.java:165)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.CreateDriverCommand.createDriver(CreateDriverCommand.java:53)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.createDriver(WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.java:170)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.getAndCheckWebDriver(WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.java:156)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner.getAndCheckWebDriver(WebDriverRunner.java:130)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.391+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.codeborne.selenide.impl.StaticDriver.getAndCheckWebDriver(StaticDriver.java:65)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.codeborne.selenide.SelenideDriver.getAndCheckWebDriver(SelenideDriver.java:206)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.codeborne.selenide.logevents.SelenideLogger.run(SelenideLogger.java:152)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.Navigator.open(Navigator.java:86)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.codeborne.selenide.SelenideDriver.open(SelenideDriver.java:97)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open(Selenide.java:127)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.tunein.mobile.appium.driverprovider.AppiumDriverProvider.getAppiumDriver(AppiumDriverProvider.java:17)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//com.tunein.mobile.tests.BaseTest.beforeTest(BaseTest.java:47)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.base@17.0.2/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:65)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:381)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:319)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:645)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:634)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.392+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:429)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:32)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:467)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at app//org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil.lambda$execute$0(ThreadUtil.java:58)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.base@17.0.2/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         Caused by:
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         Build info: version: '4.1.3', revision: '7b1ebf28ef'
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         System info: host: 'vm-osx-xcode-13.3.x-g2.4core-2c292c9b-168e-4744-b89f-3e7756272483.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1807:af7c:e23f:7704%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '12.2.1', java.version: '17.0.2'
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         Driver info: driver.version: SelenideDriver
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at app//io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:130)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at app//io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:102)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at app//io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:146)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at app//io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:180)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:567)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.393+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             ... 43 more
```

Answer (score 0):

```
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             Caused by:
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                 at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:126)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                 ... 47 more
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                 Caused by:
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                 org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                 Build info: version: '4.1.3', revision: '7b1ebf28ef'
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                 System info: host: 'vm-osx-xcode-13.3.x-g2.4core-2c292c9b-168e-4744-b89f-3e7756272483.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1807:af7c:e23f:7704%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '12.2.1', java.version: '17.0.2'
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                 Driver info: driver.version: SelenideDriver
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                     at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:72)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                     at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                     at app//io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.lambda$createSession$0(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:149)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                     at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.394+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                     at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:51)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.395+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                     at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.395+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                     at app//io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.lambda$createSession$0(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:149)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.395+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                     at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.395+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                     at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:124)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.395+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                     at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:102)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.395+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                     ... 52 more
2022-04-18T15:44:02.395+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
2022-04-18T15:44:02.395+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                     Caused by:
2022-04-18T15:44:02.395+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                     java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
2022-04-18T15:44:02.395+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1960)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.395+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2095)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.395+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                         at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:206)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.395+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:66)
2022-04-18T15:44:02.395+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]                         ... 61 more
2022-04-18T15:44:02.397+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]
```